# Open-JDK installer with icedtea plugin for windows

Tags: java, firefox, applet, icedtea

We are working with **applets** in **firefox** browser(version 48) using "OpenJDK-8". We are trying to download the installer for "**OpenJDK-8**" along with **iced-tea plugin** for **Windows-7**. Let us know some links to download OpenJDK-8 along with iced-tea plugin.

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: We already have application working with oracle java that run applet in firefox browser using icedtea plugin. We have planned to migrate this using open-jdk. So we need an installer for open-jdk in windows using iced-tea plugin support.

Comment: This is our existing old internal application. Moving the existing application to a "Plugin-Free Web" is long term process, which we have to take it up in future. Kindly guide me where to download OpenJDK-8 along with iced-tea plugin.

Comment: Hi Grace...Were you able to get OpenJDK browser plugin for windows?